# where can I learn the limitations of /LEV:n option of Robocopy command

Tags: windows, file-server, robocopy, copying, limitations

Hey I am moving a file server to another datacenter. I use robocopy but I don't know the limits of the `/LEV:n`utility. Is this "n" can be 100 or something for some crazy admins? I searched but I didn't find any info about the maximum level size of LEV.

(I am new around here and also in these type of jobs. So please inform me before giving negative feedback)

Comment: `Hey I am moving a file server to another datacenter. I use robocopy` - So you're moving the files to another file server? If you were moving the file server you would just... move the file server, right?

Comment: Yes you are right, I will try to be more careful next time while explaning my problem

Answer (score 1):

The limit is higher than you'll be able to actually make use of.

I was able to get it to accept a value of 999999999, but at 1000000000, it threw `ERROR : Invalid Parameter #3 : "/lev:1000000000"`.  Presumably, this means that the parameter will accept numbers up to 9 decimal places long, but not 10, making the maximum value 1 less than a billion.

Of course, you'll run into path length limits long before that, and I frankly can't even begin to imagine a use for high values in the `lev` parameter.

This done in Windows 7, SP1, with PowerShell 4, if anyone cares to check other OS and/or robocopy versions for comparison, though it seems like a thoroughly pointless exercise to me.

Behold my fearsome screenshot, which shows me trying to copy my C drive to a subfolder on the C drive.  I cancelled the operation as quickly as I could, of course.

[image]